# Chromium - open with home pages "pinned"

Tags: ubuntu, tabs, chromium

I'm using the latest PPA Chromium under Ubuntu and I really like the "Pinned" tabs idea.  Anyone know of a way to have my home pages open as pinned tabs automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that this is not possible yet.

Have a look at, and maybe keep an eye on in case  anything happens, on
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24781

Answer (score 2):

There is no GUI way of doing this atm, but I solved this problem by using switches in the actual launcher for Chromium. Here is what I use: 
chrome.exe page1 page2 page3 --pinned-tab-count=3
That will open up these three pages pinned. Just replace the pages with the URL of your favourite sites and change the --pinned-tab-count number accordingly.